# Create a data.frame with data.frames with different lengths

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert 6 dataframes with different lenght of rows into a single table so i can do an Anova test and check whether there are differences in their stadistics. However, i don't know how to do it.
Here's the code i used.

```
Fabtorn <- table(A1$potencia, A2$potencia, A3$potencia, B1$potencia, B2$potencia, B3$potencia)
```

The error that appears is the following:

```
Error in table(A1$potencia, A2$potencia, A3$potencia, B1$potencia, B2$potencia,  : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

I know a data frame must have the same length in all it's vectors. Is there anyway to make the other vectors the same length by adding NAs?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide details including `dput()` of your data. The question is not reproducible and the solutions can be entirely different depending upon the circumstances (if the data is paired or not etc.).

Comment: If your dataframes have some common columns you may be able to join them using the `dplyr` join functions: https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/left_join.dtplyr_step.html  A search on dplyr join will surface additional sites with examples.  See the `full_join` function to include missing common data from the input dataframes as `NA` values.